Wrong solution for: Prove $X=(\mathbb{R}^n, ||•||)$ is reflexive
As the title suggests, I have a solution to the problem, but there is a mistake, and I can't find it.
My solution:
We'll show that $X = X^*$. This is simple using the Riesz representation theorem and knowing that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Hilbert space. Since we have an isometry $y \mapsto \langle x, y \rangle$.
Now we will prove $X^* = X^{**}$. But since $X^*$ is a Hilbert space, the same method works.
That's it, we proved $X$ is reflexive.
My problem: I have proved every Hilbert space is reflexive, which I don't think is true (also I didn't use any attribute of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which makes me think this proof is wrong).
Is there a fault in the proof?
Thank you :)

It is true that every Hilbert space is reflexive. Anyway, reflexivity is more than just the existence of an abstract isomorphism with the double dual. What it means is that the canonical map $X\to X^{**}$ is an isomorphism, and this is what you need to check.

@AnneBauval: OP is asking to check the details of their proof, not for a proof.

My bad, I retract. Your 1st comment could(/should?) be an answer.

@tomasz to show the canonical map is isomorphism you mean to show she is into and onto?
do I need to show something else?

It is true that every Hilbert space is reflexive. However, the existence of an isomorphism with the double dual, which you gave an argument for, is not sufficient.
In more detail, for every topological vector space $X$, we have a canonical map $X\to X^{**}$ given by $x\mapsto (x^*\mapsto x^*(x))$. We say that $X$ is reflexive if this map is a (TVS) isomorphism. The existence of an isomorphism is not sufficient for reflexivity (in fact, there are Banach spaces which are not reflexive, but even isometrically isomorphic to their double dual).
Since this map is always linear, this amounts to showing that it is a homeomorphism. If $X$ is a normed space, then $X^{**}$ is a complete normed space and the canonical map is always continuous and injective, so by the open mapping theorem, $X$ is reflexive if and only if it is complete and this map is surjective (in fact, it is not hard to see that in this case, surjectivity implies completeness of $X$, since the canonical map $X\to X^{**}$ extends to an injective map from the completion of $X$).

So to complete my proof, I need to show that the map I defined is surjective?
Or is my mistake more fundamental?

It is. Your claim that $X=X^$ is not correct; Riesz only describes a particular isometry $X\to X^$. And to show reflexivity, you don't define any map, you need to show that the existing evaluation map $X\to X^{**}$ is an isomorphism. In this case, it so happens that it is actually the composition of the two isometries, but you did not observe this anywhere.

Excellent, Thank you for pointing it out :)
